# SQL Assembly Errors in C# Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, assemblies, compilation

I had old code that the source got lost (but we own it) so I decomplied it using reflector.net.

Now when I compile it, I get this:

```
 Error  1   The type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  C:\NCESTableGenerator\NCESTableGenerator\db\OutputTableDAO.cs   27  20  NCESTableGenerator
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you need to add a reference to `System.dll` to your project and try compiling again.

Answer (score 2):

You are *indirectly* referencing an assembly (you have added an assembly that refers to the offending assembly).  Add the reference and you should be set.